# Is the video recording possible in the background service?

Tags: android

I've tried video recording in the background.
But had failed.

Under normal circumstances, the recording works properly.
However, if HOME key down-> Home screen or Other Activity is running,
recording terminates.

In such a situation, I want to record continuously.
I want to record whole process!

What should I do?

thanks.
-Michael

Comment: what do you mean by video recording, screen or using the camera ??

Comment: The camera, I use.
I already know this privacy issue.

Do anyone else have a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot video record in the background as far as I know. This is partially for privacy reasons.

Comment: thanks,CommonsWare.
But I want to solve this issue, I'm looking for other ideas.
Do you have a good idea or good advice?
:-)